# Stringstream c++ while loop

Tags: c++, loops, stringstream, zero

Program finds integeres between commas like "2,33,5" -> 2 33 5.
The problem is why is it working if I put for example string like "0,12,4".
shouldn't the stringstream put 0 into tmp so the loop was like while(0) at the beginning?

```
 vector<int> parseInts(string str) {
 stringstream ss(str);   //getting string 
 vector<int> result;
 char ch;
 int tmp;
 while(ss >> tmp) {      //while(IS IT INTEGER ALREADY OR NOT?)
     result.push_back(tmp);
     ss >> ch;           
}
return result;
```

Comment: you are going to the whitespace.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Look more closely at the example input. There is no whitespace.

Comment: `>>The problem is why is it working if I put for example string like "0,12,4"` why is it a problem? You don't want it to read 0?

Comment: @KillzoneKid He's just surprised that it works, he thought `while()` would be testing the value of being extracted.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see ;) Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> shouldn't the stringstream put 0 into tmp so the loop was like while(0) at the beginning?

The while condition is `ss >> tmp`. If you look at the documentation for `cin`, you will find that `operator>>()` returns a `istream&`. It does **not** return the input that you just read, in this case the `int` value `0`.

In addition, `istream` (or one of it's base classes) overloads `operator bool()` which allows `istream` objects to be implicitly converted to a `bool`, the type required as the result of a `while` statements  condition. An `istream` object will evaluate as `false` whenever an error occurs during the call to `operator>>()`. If there is no error, then it evaluates to `true`.

Since the input `0` is a valid `int`, the `while` loop continues the next iteration.